# How to create a channel that only a given role can see?

Tags: discord.js

```
 msg.guild.createRole({
    name: msg.author.username, 
    color: "#ff0000"
  }).then(role => {
    msg.member.addRole(role)
  })
```

I want only this role can see this channel

`` guild.createChannel( `${msg.author.username}`, "text")
    .then(channel => {
    let category = guild.channels.find(c => c.name == "INFO" && c.type == "category"); ``

```
if (!category) throw new Error("Category channel does not exist");
 channel.setParent(category.id).then(
 channel.send(embed)
```

it is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to create a channel that only a given role can see. It's called **[Overwrite Permission](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.6.4/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=overwritePermissions)**
To add new permission in a channel, use like this

```js
<Text Channel>.overwritePermission(<Role>,
      {
       VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
       SEND_MESSAGES: true /* you can remove send messages part if need */ 
      }
    )
```

Replace `<Text Channel>` with text channel defined, `<Role>` with role defined as your code like this

```js
msg.guild.createRole({
    name: msg.author.username, 
    color: "#ff0000"
}).then(role => {
    msg.member.addRole(role)
    guild.createChannel( `${msg.author.username}`, "text")
    .then(channel => { 
        channel.overwritePermission(role, {
             VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
             SEND_MESSAGES: true
        })
    }) 
})
```

Also you can read the docs about it by pressing [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/11.6.4/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=overwritePermissions)

Comment: This is a good answer. Thank you for providing not just the correct code, but also an explanation of what's needed and what's changed, along with references.